# cannot build up a django project

Tags: python, django

every time I tried to build a django project. I have no initialized files like manage.py in my project.

Then I tried to create the project on command line, I got this:

```
C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.9.3-py3.4.egg\django\bin> python .\django-admin.py startproject "MySite"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\django-admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core import management
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.3-py3.4.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.apps import apps
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.3-py3.4.egg\django\apps\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .config import AppConfig
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.3-py3.4.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.utils.module_loading import module_has_submodule
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.9.3-py3.4.egg\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 67, in <module>
    from importlib.util import find_spec as importlib_find
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_spec'
```

Somebody could help me? I really appreciate your help.
ps: python3.4, django_1.9

Answer (score 0):

U need to put your code here because it seems you are having too many import errors

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a Django project from within your Python installation (`C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Django-1.9.3-py3.4.egg\django\bin>`).

Try going to your home directory and trying there. `django-admin` should be in `C:\Python34\Scripts\` and that should be in your `PATH` so you should be able to call it from anywhere.

PS Use virtualenv

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said, I put the path of django-admin in my PATH system variable and try to create project in another directory, but I still have the same error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'find_spec'

Comment: I fixed the error by updating my pydev version to 3.5. There must be a conflict between pydev3.4 and django1.9_x